# Return an empty string to an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have an AJAX call to a function:

```
$('#DeviceType').change(function () {
   // when the selection of the device type drop down changes 
   // get the new value
   var devicetype = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("GetEquipmentCode")',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { deviceTypeID: devicetype },
      success: function (result) {
         // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the EquipmentCode text box
         $('#EquipmentCode').val(result);
      }
   });
});
```

with the function being

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetEquipmentCode(int deviceTypeID)
{
   var deviceType = _db.DeviceTypes.Single(d => d.ID == deviceTypeID);

   return (deviceType.EquipmentCode != null) ? 
                      deviceType.EquipmentCode.Code : 
                      String.Empty;
}
```

However, if the function returns `String.Empty` the string I actually get in my text box is "`[object XMLDocument]`".  How do I get a result of empty string in my text box?

Comment: Is the AJAX response supposed to be XML or JSON? and is this coming from WCF or an MVC ActionMethod?

Comment: MVC action method.  And XML or JSON - maybe that is what I should be returning instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is probably the easiest.

Try:

```
$('#DeviceType').change(function () {
   // when the selection of the device type drop down changes 
   // get the new value
   var devicetype = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("GetEquipmentCode")',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: { deviceTypeID: devicetype },
      success: function (result) {
         // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the EquipmentCode text box
         $('#EquipmentCode').val(result);
      }
   });
});
```

Then in your ActionMethod

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetEquipmentCode(int deviceTypeID)
{
   var deviceType = _db.DeviceTypes.Single(d => d.ID == deviceTypeID);

   return Json((deviceType.EquipmentCode != null) ? 
                      deviceType.EquipmentCode.Code : 
                      String.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  .... 
  data: { deviceTypeID: devicetype },
  dataType : 'html',
  ...
```

by default, jquery tries to guess and sometimes might not be accurate.

[More info here](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)

Comment: just changed `"text"` to "`html`"